# Scope exception rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to define an inventory for all my articles but I want to exclude the articles that are sent to me with a parameter.

Here is what the relationship looks like:

```
  Article
    has_many :tags, through: :articletags
  ArticleTags
    belongs_to :article
    belongs_to :tags
  Tags
    has_many :article, through: articletags
```

Here's a method to define the one without the tags in my models:

```
def self.by_not_tags(tag)
  joins(:tags).where('tags.title != ?', tag)
end
```

Here's how I call it in my view:

```
<%= link_to (tag.title), articles_path(:scope => tag.title) %>
```

Here's my controller:

```
 def custom
    if params[:scope].nil?
      @articles = Article.all(:order => 'created_at DESC')
    else
      @articles = Article.by_tags(params[:scope])
      @articles2 = Article.by_not_tags(params[:scope])
    end
  end
```

The goal is to see all the articles with a tag first, and then to show the other ones without that tag, so I don't have duplicates.

My issue is with the joins, but I am not sure how to find the article without tags. Maybe an except would work, but I am not sure what kind of query would work for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming ArticleTag model needs to validate the presence of both article_id and tag_id,

```
Article.where('article_tag_id is null')
```

If I do not assume that above validation stated,

```
Article.where('not exists (select 1 from article_tags where article_id = articles.id)')
```